# Simplest Way to Hide Part of a Class' public methods/Interface

Tags: java, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I am trying to design the GUI front end of a robot simulator (effectively a simple game). However, I don't know the best way of passing the simulator components (such as Robots and Walls) to the display. I want to hide the non-display oriented information of the components (such as the Robots mass), yet still be able to recognise each component im printing, i.e. when I'm drawing components I want to draw Robots differently that I do Walls (maybe the robot will have a name tag or something).

Here is a picture that will hopefully explain the design:
[image: Program Design]

Maybe there is a useful design pattern that I haven't come across yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the model-view-controller design pattern. It separates data (robot's speed, size,...), presentation (robot's shape and its paint method) and behavior (increase robot speed).

To answer your question - the simplest way to hide parts of a class's API is to split this class into multiple pieces (model, view, controller) and connect them according to some pattern (MVC, or model-view-presenter, they are many of them).

**EDIT**: Sorry for that I didn't provide any example. My suggestion is just to split Robot into two classes:

- **RobotData** (contains speed, size,... provides getters/setters, simple java bean object)
- **RobotUi** (provides shape method (using private reference of RobotData) )

The Simulator then contains collection of RobotUi (Simulator is a *model*) and SimulatorDisplay (=*view*) iterates through the UI objects when performing paint method. The RobotData will be hidden inside RobotUi.

Comment: I have actually implemented MVC. I just didn't put in in the diagram because I thought it would add complexity. A SimulatorDisplay object is an observer of a Simulator (no need for controller between passive view and model). The display gets a reference to a Simulator object each update(). But how do I get the information to print a Robot without getting the full Robot? (For example, I don't want its speed and motor configurations).

Comment: Your edited suggestion is similar to my 'initial idea' in my diagram (I have the Robot implement an GuiRobot interface, and only pass that to the SimulatorDisplay). I have decided to go with this- wrapping the Robot with a RobotUi which will have a reduced public interface- one to be used by the GUI.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should design this by interface contract.

I would make your walls, robots and sensors be implementations of various 'things' the UI needs to know about. Only those interfaces should be shared between the UI and your Model.

For example, Robot, Sensor should implement an interface called Printable:

```
public interface Printable {
   Shap getShape();
}
```

Wall should implement an extended interface PrintableTexture

```
public interface PrintableTexture extends Printable {
   Texture getTexture();
}
```

You could also create and implement data provider type interfaces for angle, direction, etc.

For example:

```
public interface RangeProvider {
   Range getRange();
}

public interface DirectionProvider {
   Direction getDirection();
}

public interface SensorProvider {
   Sensor[] getSensors();
}
```

The main point is that the 'printing' code would then check for what interfaces are implemented by the Printable object (or list of Printable objects) that has been passed to the it and react appropriately.

Looking at your comments, I think that PrintableRobot, PrintableWall, etc is a misunderstanding of the fundamental concept of what an interface is. An interface should be more about 'what something provides or how you can use it' versus a concrete implementation of how this is achieved. By putting Robot, Wall, etc in Printable you are giving an indication of implementation.

This aside, have you considered the [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)?? You could have each entity implement the accept part of the visitor pattern and have your printing code be a special implementation that only takes what it needs out of a deeper knowledge of what each entity does.... It's not what I would do, but it may suit you...

Comment: Thanks. I have tried your first suggestion. However, due to each component (Robot, Wall & Sensor) having different properties that are relavent for printing (Robot has a getDirection and Sensor has getRange), I end up having a Printable interface for each: PrintableRobot, PrintableSensor, etc as seen in the bottom of the diagram. I'm not sure if this is good or not.

Comment: I reasearched and experimented with the visitor pattern. However, I came to the conclusion that the visitor pattern's function is to add functionality to classes, but have this functionality reside in another 'visitor' class. It does not hide the non-GUI methods from the GUI code (the visitor will have a reference to a Robot). Having said that, I will keep the visitor pattern in mind, as I can see how it is applicable to this problem. Thanks.